# getItemCount() of my RecyclerView adapter returns 0 even though I have items in it

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

My `RecyclerView` returns a `getItemCount()` of 0 even though I have items in it. What can be the reason?

**In Activity**

`int length = mAdapter.getItemCount();`

**In Adapter**

```java
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return reportlist.size();
}
```

**onCreate() method in my activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_listing);

mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
flightViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(FlightViewModel.class);
userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ReportListingActivity.this);
mAdapter = new ReportAdapter(reportitems, ReportListingActivity.this);

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

userViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(ReportListingActivity.this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<User> users) {
                user_details = getUsers();
                user_name = user_details[0];
                user_id = user_details[1];

                flights = flightViewModel.getFlightReports(user_name,user_id);
                if (flights.size() == 0) return;

                reportitems.clear();
                reportItemsCopy.clear();

                for(int i = 0; i <flights.size();i++){
                    String flightnumber = flights.get(i).getFlightNumber();
                    String departuredate = flights.get(i).getDate();
                    String status = flights.get(i).getFlight_closure_status();
                    String user_name = flights.get(i).getName();
                    String user_id = flights.get(i).getStaffID();


                    reportitems.add(new ReportItem(flightnumber,departuredate,status, user_name, user_id));


                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: have you tried checking the contents of `reportlist` when the `getItemCount()` is invoked?

Comment: @GauthamM I tried, but it gives and error - `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`. I can see the item in the recycler view on my activity though

Comment: are you sure that the objects are the same?

Comment: yes. If I click on a button on my activity to get the get item count, then it returns the correct count. However, in `onCreate()`, it returns 0 always

Comment: @GauthamM I cant seem to figure out the reason for this, it is very strange

Comment: @GauthamM I have updated the question above. I have added the code for where I am adding items to the RecyclerView. Maybe that might help give more clarity.

Comment: @IanBell, please, add piece of code (in context of method) where you set the adapter for the RV and all related stuffs

Comment: @S-Sh I just updated teh question and added in the code for the onCreate() method where I am setting the adapter for the RV

Comment: @IanBell, it seems pretty valid... May be, there are some mistakes in the adapter?.. As well, check for warnings in LogCat

Comment: @S-Sh can it be because I am initialising my reportitems inside my userviewmodel which is asynchronous?

Comment: @IanBell, you pass `reportitems` into adapter's constructor. But how do you define and initialize it?

Comment: I just initialise it as an empty array list my activity class right before onCreate method - `ArrayList<ReportItem> reportitems = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

you should put your adapter class to make it easy for others to help, but anyway.
you passed reportItems to the adapter constructor in the onCreate() but i don't see that you had initialize it and didn't put any items in the list, try to initialize it and put put any item in reportItems list in the onCreate() method before passing it to adapter constructor

Comment: I only want to put items in it inside the userviewmodel.getAllUsers.observe() method which is asynchronous.